# Add a method to a resource in AWS API Gateway

Tags: aws-api-gateway, aws-powershell

How does one add a method to a resource in AWS API Gateway, using the AWS Powershell module and powershell?

### What I have tried so far

This powershell script does not work:

```
$op = @{Op='add'; Path='/ResourceMethods'; Value='GET'}
Update-AGResource -RestApiId $id  -resourceId $resid `
   -PatchOperation $op -region $region @creds
```

Amazon documentation on [this page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-lambda-proxy-integrations.html), shows an example of the equivalent using the AWS CLI tool ...

```
aws apigateway put-method --rest-api-id te6si5ach7 \
       --region us-west-2 \
       --resource-id 2jf6xt \
       --http-method ANY \
       --authorization-type "NONE"
```

... but I don't want to use the CLI. I want to use powershell instead.

I think the problem might be the `Path` item of $op. The documentation is not very clear on what the path for methods should be.

Answer (score 1):

I've solved it.

Update-AGResource is the wrong cmdlet to add a method.
The correct cmdlet is [Write-AGMethod](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/powershell/latest/reference/Index.html).